# XmlHttpReqest missing parameter on 2nd form submit (IE only)

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, xmlhttprequest, url-parameters

I have a simple  in my jsp with some input fields. It works perfectly fine in most browser and not so much in IE.

When the form is used in IE only the first submit will work. Every submit after that "fails" as some of the parameters from the form are missing. This is NOT an issue on Chrome or Firefox. If I reload the page between each submit it works fine on IE as well, but this is not an option.

form:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="receiver.htm">
<table>
    <tr id="name">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input id="input_name" name="name"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td><input id="amount" name="amount" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unit</td>
        <td><input id="unit" name="unit" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="submit"/></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/receiver.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public String receive(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
    String name = httpServletRequest.getParameter("name");
    String amount = httpServletRequest.getParameter("amount");
    UnitType unit = UnitType.getValue(httpServletRequest.getParameter("unit"));
}
```

UnitType is an enum I made. And it throws the following exception after 2nd submit with IE as some of the parameters return as null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
```

Comment: Not sure but could be a caching issue. Just append a hidden parameter equal to current time stamp and see if this works.

Comment: Or just do a CTRL-F5 page reload.

Comment: although I'm not saying cache isnt the problem I dont see how that could be as the first submit does contain the parameters.. it is only further submits that the parameters are missing.. a cache problem would more likely give me the opposite problem where data from last submit would be present in further submits

Comment: Stephen C - that does solve the problem.. so does a normal F5, but that is not a viable option for me at this point :)